# Vlook Up Elements from another dataframe for creating MultiIndex DataFrame in Python

Tags: pandas, indexing, hierarchical

There are 2 Dataframes and one hierarchical index (pandas multiIndex).
Dataframe A has a list of ID's and Names.
Dataframe B has a list of Name combinations and a similarity score.

I want, based on the multiindex to pick up the values from Dataframe A and check if the combination does exist in DataFrame B. If yes, I want to bring to my Multindex dataframe the similiarity score, otherwise just 0.

DataFrame A (Original Dataframe)

```
test= pd.DataFrame({'row':['a','b','c','d'],'col_A' : ["Alexis","Alexi","Peter","Pete"]})

test = test.set_index('row');test
Out:   
    row   col_A   
    a     Alexis
    b     Alexi
    c     Peter
    d     Pete
```

DataFrame B (Name Similarity)

```
names = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ["Alexis","Alexi","Peter","Pete"]
                    ,'B' : ["Alexi","Alexis","Pete","Peter"]
                    , "similarity" : [0.9,0.9,0.8,0.8]})
Out:
       A       B      similarity
0   Alexis   Alexi         0.9
1   Alexi    Alexis        0.9
2   Peter    Pete          0.8
3   Pete     Peter         0.8
```

Multiindex

```
# Creating a Pandas MultiIndex 
arrays = [['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
          ['b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
indexy = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
```

to iterate through the index I use the below function, however, I am not sure how to adjust it, in order to bring the similarity score when exists or 0 when it does not.

```
a = pd.DataFrame((test.reindex(indexy.get_level_values(0)).values (?) test.reindex(indexy.get_level_values(1))).values,index=indexy,columns=test.columns)
```

Where a I want to look like this:

```
   row      similarity
first second           
a     b             0.9
      c             0
      d             0
b     c             0
      d             0
c     d             0.8
```

Comment: Do you need to create a multiindex DF for another reason that getting the result you expect?

Comment: I am creating 3 multiindex dataframe that I will combine later on. The first datafrme incorporates numerical data comparison (so the difference between entities a,bc,d,...) The second one incorporates a categorical comparison, match not match and last this one where I want to incorporate the string similarity based on stting values. Later I will use this merged dataset as an input to an algorithm. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, to get `a` I was wondering why you were using a multiindex df.

Comment: Sort of I am using hierarchical indexing which is the MultiIndex section of the code above. However, I am not sure how to combine this with vlookup on the similarity score table. a  is not a fully finalised command. This is exactly what I am asking. How I should correctly code a to give me the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you are not too much into the multiindex, here is one way to get your data as you expect:

```
import pandas as pd
test= pd.DataFrame({'row':['a','b','c','d'],'col_A' : ["Alexis","Alexi","Peter","Pete"]})
names = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ["Alexis","Alexi","Peter","Pete"],
                    'B' : ["Alexi","Alexis","Pete","Peter"],
                    "similarity" : [0.9,0.9,0.8,0.8]})
```

Note I don't `set_index` `test` but you can do it, it would slightly change the following (see the comments). You can create `a` dataframe a such as:

```
import itertools
a = pd.DataFrame([p for p in itertools.combinations(test['col_A'], 2)],columns =['A','B'],
                 index=['%s,%s'%p for p in itertools.combinations(test['row'], r=2)])
# here if you did set_index your test, then replace 
# index=['%s,%s'%p for p in itertools.combinations(test['row'], r=2)] by 
# index=['%s,%s'%p for p in itertools.combinations(test.index, r=2)]
```

And it's look like:

```
          A      B
a,b  Alexis  Alexi
a,c  Alexis  Peter
a,d  Alexis   Pete
b,c   Alexi  Peter
b,d   Alexi   Pete
c,d   Peter   Pete
```

Then you can use `reset_index` (to get current index as a column but it depends of what you want exactly) `merge` with `names` on columns A and B, fill `nan` with 0, drop the two columns A and B, and rename (if necessary):

```
a = a.reset_index().merge(names, how = 'left', on = ['A','B']).fillna(0).\
     drop(labels = ['A','B'], axis=1).rename(columns = {'index':'row', 'similarity':'col_A'})
```

Let me know if you can do what you want after

EDIT: with the new output you look for, you can do:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([p for p in itertools.combinations(test['col_A'], 2)],columns =['A','B'],
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([p for p in itertools.combinations(test.index, r=2)], names=['first', 'second']))
```

Note: `itertools` generate tuples that are used in `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` to define your multiindex DF.

Now you can `merge` (to keep the multiindex, you need to `reset_index` before and `set_index` after:

```
a = a.reset_index().merge(names, how = 'left', on = ['A','B']).fillna(0).\
         drop(labels = ['A','B'], axis=1).set_index(['first', 'second'])
```

Comment: Hi Ben, That is great but I need the data frame to be with hierarchical indexing. Itertools do not retain the level. Is it possible to do the same with using the hierarchical index?

Comment: I can fill the hierarchical table as follows:df = pd.DataFrame(index=indexy, columns=["similarity"])

df ["A"]= test.reindex(indexy.get_level_values(0)).values
df ["B"]= test.reindex(indexy.get_level_values(1)).values   But how can I merge them based on the values?

Comment: @A.Papa I think my EDIT should do what you look for, but if not, I'm not sure I understand what you want and why you want to use the `test.reindex(indexy.get_level_values(0)).values`. Hope it helps anyway :)

Comment: I have updated my question. I need a hierarchical dataframe at the end. This means 2 level indexes. I do not need to use necessarily this `test.reindex(indexy.get_level_values(0)).values` just to result to a dataframe based on the indexy hierarchical indexes.

Comment: @A.Papa if you try my EDIT of yesterday you have the hierarchical DF

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the further explanation as well!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it using multiindexes, `merge` and `map`:

```
from itertools import combinations

a = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(combinations(test.col_A,2))))
a = a.merge(names, left_index=True, right_on=['A','B'],how='left').fillna(0)
testmap = test.reset_index().set_index('col_A').squeeze()

a['A'] = a.A.map(testmap)
a['B'] = a.B.map(testmap)
a = a.set_index(['A','B'])
a
```

Output:

```
     similarity
A B            
a b         0.9
  c         0.0
  d         0.0
b c         0.0
  d         0.0
c d         0.8
```

### Details

- Create MultiIndex using combinations from itertools
- Merge empty dataframe with multiindex to 'names' dataframe and fill NaN with zero
- Use set_index to create a series to map 'col_A' back to 'row' values in test